# Select on same table without subselect

Tags: sql, select

I have **payment**, **period** and **event** tables. For each employee, month and year, I want to return payment.value (SALARY) and payment.value (ADDITIONAL, like a bonus) on same row, depending of event number. The event number 10015 represent the ADDITIONAL, and event number 4986 represent the SALARY.

I was able to reach my goal:

```
SELECT payment.employee_id EMPLOYEE_ID, payment.value SALARY,

(SELECT payment.value ADDITIONAL FROM payment
    INNER JOIN period ON payment.period_id = period.id
    INNER JOIN event ON payment.event_id = event.id

    WHERE period.month = 7 
      AND period.year = 2021 
      AND payment.employee_id = 71
      AND event.number = 10015
) ADDITIONAL

FROM payment

INNER JOIN period ON payment.period_id = period.id
INNER JOIN event ON payment.event_id = event.id

WHERE period.month = 7 
    AND period.year = 2021 
    AND payment.employee_id = 71
    AND event.number = 4986
```

Result:

[image: RESULT]

But now I'm trying to refactor my query so I don't have nested SELECTS. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
SELECT p.employee_id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN e.number = 4986 THEN p.value END) as SALARY,
       SUM(CASE WHEN e.number = 10015 THEN p.value END) as ADDITIONAL
FROM payment p JOIN
     period pe
     ON p.period_id = pe.id JOIN
     event e
     ON p.event_id = e.id
WHERE pe.month = 7 AND
      pe.year = 2021 
      p.employee_id = 71 AND
      e.number IN (4986, 10015)
GROUP BY p.employee_id;
```

Note:  This is not 100% equivalent to you query, but I think it is what you want to do.  This returns one row with `salary` and `additional` on one row.  If there are multiple rows for the employee's salary in the period, then this returns one row whereas yours would return each row separately.